# XADES4j - XML signature verification error - Signature node not specified

Tags: java, xml, verification, xml-signature, xades4j

I came to sign an XML file with XAdES4j, but when verifing it, I always get "Signature node not specified". Apparently the `signatureParent` is `null`! How to fix that?

Here is my code:

```
FileSystemDirectoryCertStore certStore = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore(".");
KeyStore trustAnchors = createAndLoadJKSKeyStore(".\\myStore", "mystorepass");
CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(trustAnchors, false, certStore.getStore());

XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
XadesVerifier v = p.newVerifier();

Document sourceDoc = Signapp.getDocument(".\\TEST.XML.FILE.xml");

Element signatureParent = (Element)sourceDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, Constants._TAG_SIGNATURE).item(0);;
XAdESVerificationResult r = v.verify(signatureParent,null);
```

Comment: How are you getting the document? Is the DocumentBuilderFactory set to be namespace aware? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)

Comment: hi I posted my getDocument methud as an answer .. would you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

here is my getDocument method :

```
        File fXmlFile = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        return doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
dbFactory.SetNamespaceAware(true);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)